# Send message to object via class scope (metaprogramming)

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I need a way to send a message from *stuff* method (via metaprogramming) which executes *my_method* on the object scope. There's a good way of doing that without inserting more code on Dummy class?

```
class Dummy
  stuff :final_value do
    value :my_method
  end

  def my_method
    10.5
  end

  def final_value
    0
  end
end
```

Expected return:

```
dummy = Dummy.new
dummy.final_value
=> 10.5
```

The idea is to take the methods on *value* args and find a way to map those values from the object scope, which is this example is 10.5.

Posting a temporary solution down there.

Comment: This looks a bit difficult - it surely is possible, probably very easy, but on a first glance it seems as if you call an instance method on your object, yet you want to use a completely different mehod on the class instance. For changing the meaning of self, look at .clas_eval, .instance_eval and instance_eval(&block) if block_given?

Comment: You are calling a method, i.e. stuff(), that doesn't exist.  So you need to solve that problem before asking your question.

Comment: I can think of many ways to get the desired result, but I have no idea which one you want since your question is so vague.

Comment: Your question will be closed if you don't clarify with an edit, ASAP.  I think all you need do is say you want to add a method `stuff` that will result in your expected output, but you don't know how to write that method.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
class Dummy
  def stuff
    self.class.send(:define_method, :final_value) do
      my_method
    end
  end

  def my_method
    10.5
  end

  def final_value
    0
  end
end

dummy = Dummy.new
dummy.stuff
dummy.final_value #=> 10.5
```

The purpose of the method `stuff` is to change the method `final_value` to:

```
def final_value
  my_method
end
```

so we need to do, dynamically, the equivalent of:

```
class Dummy
  def final_value
    my_method
  end
end
```

Here, when `final_value` is created, `self` is `Dummy`. We therefore need to instruct `Dummy` to define the method `final_value` as above, thereby replacing its earlier definition. Fortunately, there's a method that does just that: [Module#define_method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Module.html#method-i-define_method).

To execute `:define_method`, we need only send it, together with its argument `:final_value` and a block that is to be the body of `:final_value`, to `Dummy`, using the method [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
def stuff
  Dummy.send(self.class.send(:define_method, :final_value) do
    my_method
  end
end
```

That works fine, but suppose we were to rename the class to, say, `Smartie`? We'd have to remember to change `Dummy` to `Smartie` in the method `stuff`.  It's better to replace `Dummy` with `self.class`. By the way, this is one of the few instances where you do need to include `self.`, as `class` alone is interpreted as the keyword `class`, as in `class Dummy`.

**Edit:** I may have misunderstood the question. (See comments below.) The following may be what you want:

```
class Dummy
  def self.stuff(method, &block)
    send(:define_method, method, &block)
  end

  def my_method
    10.5
  end

  def final_value
    0
  end

  stuff :final_value do
    my_method
  end
end

Dummy.new.final_value #=> 10.5
```

Note, because Ruby parses the lines sequentially, building the class as it goes,

```
stuff :final_value do
  my_method
end
```

must appear after the other methods.

Comment: This will not work. `stuff` is an instance method here, not a class method.

Comment: @sethvargo, yes it is an instance method, but `self.class => Dummy`, so I don't understand your point.

Comment: in his example, he wants to use `stuff` at the class level to define a new method... unless I'm misinterpreting the OP.

Comment: The OP said `stuff` is to be a method. To invoke it, one needs `Dummy.stuff` or `Dummy.new.stuff`, depending on whether it is to be a class or instance method. Neither of those statements are shown. Nor is there an `initialize` method that does that. I assumed it was to be an instance method, but it's a trivial change to make it a class method. Incidentally, what suggested to you that it should be a class method?

Comment: but look at the OP's example usage - it's a class method, not an instance method...

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "example usage". There is no `Dummy.stuff` (or `dummy.stuff`), so what leads you to think it should be a class method?  But if the OP wants it to be a class method, as I said above, it's a trivial change.

Comment: http://cl.ly/image/1r1J3Z2L2b3y/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-08%20at%207.03.15%20PM.png. From the question, it seems like he is asking for a class method that calls an instance method...

Comment: @sethvargo, with the larger font I now understand your point. I took the first three lines of `Dummy` to have been a failed attempt at writing a method stuff, as the first sentence of the question suggested to me that the method `stuff` was already there, not a method to be added. I've edited my answer.

Comment: yea, I think it's unclear what OP is asking tbh. I reversed my downvote on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary way of dealing with it was executing code on define_method scope, which is the object scope itself. The solution is not fully tested but the idea is pretty much that:

```
def stuff(method_name, &block)
  subject = Stuff.new(block)

  # Defining the final_value method and executing code on object scope.

  define_method method_name do
    # making the sum on object scope (demand is a list of *value* args, 
    # which is a list of methods to execute on object scope)
    #
    # The logic here is to sum them to return as final_value result

    subject.total = subject.demand.map do |method|
      self.send(method)
    end.reduce(:+)

    subject.total
  end

  subject.evaluate!
end

class Stuff
  attr_accessor :demand, :total

  def initialize(stuff_block)
    @stuff_block = stuff_block
    @total = 0
  end

  # Brings all stuff block into Stuff class
  def evaluate!
    @stuff_block.call
  end

  # The main problem was this.
  # The solution was mapping those demanded methods into a demand local variable,
  # then accessing this variable on define_method scope inside *stuff* method, which is the
  # object scope itself. Bahn!
  def value(*args)
    @demand = args
  end
end
```